# Scroll arrow in navigation menu bar using Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have chosen a navigation menu bar with tabs for fulfilling my application requirement.

If I set seven tabs in navigation mode, the window width is good enough to show all the tabs. When I add more than seven, the tabs are visible, and I can access them by scrolling horizontally. Although, tabs are visible only on scrolling to the right, and the user may not be aware that more tabs are available, so I want to add scroll arrows to my toolbar.

I am using Polymer. How do I add scroll arrows to my toolbar? Thanks.

Also I want to add scrollbar to app drawer also. Please help me in that too.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? Maybe a snippet or fiddle. Also mention what CSS framework you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Polymer's `<paper-tabs>`, you could set the [`scrollable`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/paper-tabs#property-scrollable) property to enable the arrows for scrolling.

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-tabs selected="0" scrollable>
        <paper-tab>NUMBER ONE ITEM</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>ITEM TWO</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>THE THIRD ITEM</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>THE ITEM FOUR</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>FIFTH</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>THE SIXTH TAB</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>NUMBER SEVEN</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>EIGHT</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>NUMBER NINE</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>THE TENTH</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>THE ITEM ELEVEN</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>TWELFTH ITEM</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/woQJZW?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @AnkitaJoshi No problem :)